# title in amsart

Tags: amsart

I am typesetting a paper in LaTeX:`\documentclass{amsart}`. I compiled it with `pdflatex` but the `.pdf` document. does not have abstract,title and key words.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add your document as a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to the question

Comment: Did you add `\maketitle`?To not need to guess we need to see a minimal working example.

Comment: Many thanks for your guide,the command \maketitle dropped before when I insert it is Ok.